# How to retrive email of specific partner ID that user enters and send it back to controller.

Tags: sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am having a problem.
I don't know sequelize.js properly. 
I have a HTML form as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Forget Password</title>
</head>
<body>
Forget Password: <br/>
<form action="/forgetpasswordpartner" method="POST">
    Enter PartnerID: 
    <input type="text" name="partnerid">
    <button type="submit" value="Send Email">Send Email</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have controller as:

```
exports.sendresetlinkpartner = function (req, res, next) {
var partnerid = req.body.partnerid;
var token = randomstring.generate({
    length: 100,
    charset: 'alphanumeric',
    capitalization: 'uppercase'
});
var link = "http://localhost:3000/forgetpasswordpartner/" + token;
forgetpasswordmodel.sendresetemailpartner(partnerid, token, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        res.send('Email not found in database');
    }
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'xxxx',
            port:xxx,
            secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
            auth: {
                user: 'xxxxxx@xxxx.com', // generated ethereal user
                pass: 'xxxxxxxxx' // generated ethereal password
            },
            //if email is sent via localhost
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        });
        let mailOptions = {
            from: '"xxxxxx" <xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com>', // sender address
            to: email, // list of receivers
            subject: 'Reset Password', // Subject line
            text: 'A password reset for your account was requested', // plain text body
            html: "Please click the button below to change your password.<br><a href=" + link + ">" + "<h2>Change your password</h2>" + "</a> "
            // html body
        };
        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {

                res.send('Couldnot send Reset Password email.Please try again later');
                return console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
                // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
                console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
                // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
                // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
            }
        });
        res.send('To Change your password, a link has been sent to your email.Check your mail');
    }
})
}
```

And this is my model:

```
exports.sendresetemailpartner=function(partnerid,token,callback1,callback2){

partner.findOne({where:{'partnerid':partnerid}}).then(partner.update({'token':token},{where:{'companyemail':email}})).then((partner)=>{
    if(!partner){
        console.log('Email not registered');
        callback1();
    }
    else{
        console.log('Token Updated');
        callback2();
    }
})
```

I know my model is wrong
**What I want is first check whether 'partnerid' exist in database or not and if exist, insert a token in same row record and retrieve email of that partner id and send that emailid back to controller for storing on 'email' variable and sending that mail**

Can anyone help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate js file for sending email. As the email will be accessed by some other methods too. write it as generic which accepting two parameters.

```
//utils.js
module.exports = {
    sendEmail: function(toEmail, link) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: 'xxxx',
                port: xxx,
                secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
                auth: {
                    user: 'xxxxxx@xxxx.com', // generated ethereal user
                    pass: 'xxxxxxxxx' // generated ethereal password
                },
                //if email is sent via localhost
                tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            });

            let mailOptions = {
                from: '"xxxxxx" <xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com>', // sender address
                to: toEmail, // list of receivers
                subject: 'Reset Password', // Subject line
                text: 'A password reset for your account was requested', // plain text body
                html: "Please click the button below to change your password.<br><a href=" + link + ">" + "<h2>Change your password</h2>" + "</a> "
                // html body
            };

            // send mail with defined transport object
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                if (error) {

                    res.send('Couldnot send Reset Password email.Please try again later');
                    //return console.log(error);
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
                    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
                    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
                    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
                    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
                    resolve("success")
                }
            });
        });
    }
}


//Require util.js

import Utils from '../utils'

exports.sendresetlinkpartner = function(req, res, next) {

    var partnerid = req.body.partnerid;
    var token = randomstring.generate({
        length: 100,
        charset: 'alphanumeric',
        capitalization: 'uppercase'
    });
    var link = "http://localhost:3000/forgetpasswordpartner/" + token;

    partner.findOne({
        where: {
            'partnerid': partnerid
        }
    }).then((fetchedPartner) => {
        fetchedPartner.update({
            token: token
        }).then((postUpdate) => {
            if (!postUpdate) {
                console.log('Email not registered');
            } else {
                Utils.sendEmail('xyz@gmail.com', link).then((postEmail) => {
                    // your logic for success
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```